# Question on Badiou's set theoretical philosophy using trilogy of diagrams, maths and words

Tags: set-theory

In Being and Event Badiou defines $\in$ as *the sign of belonging. Belonging is equivalent to presentation*.
Imagine a situation-set called $VFC$, also shown as a diagram:
[Situation-Set VFC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxoFY.png)
.

In this case $\beta$ belongs to the situation-set $(\beta \in VFC)$ (i.e. is presented), and $\alpha$ is included $(\alpha \subset VFC)$ in the situation-set (i.e. is represented).

We know that whatever is represented (i.e. included) also belongs to the power-set (i.e. the metastructure of $VFC$) which is written $P(VFC)$.

So we can say $\alpha \subset VFC$ but also $\alpha \in P(VFC).$

Now my question is, how do I draw the correct diagram of $P(VFC)$? Is it:
[Power-set of VFC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rKUv.png).

Now for $\beta$, in words, Badiou states that $\beta$ belongs to the situation-set $VFC$ (presentation) and is equally included (representation).

So according to the attached diagrams we have $\beta\in VFC$ but also if $\beta\in P(VFC)$ then $\beta\subset VFC$, so we have both $\beta\in VFC$ and $\beta\subset VFC$? Is that correct?

Badiou says this term is a *normal* term, i.e. $\beta$ is *normal* term, in contrast to $\alpha$ that is a *excrescence* term (represented but not presented).

But how does that make sense w.r.t. the diagrams, what is not consistent here? The maths? The words? The diagrams? How can $\beta$ both $\in$ and $\subset$, how does that make sense with the diagrams?

Comment: With all due respect to Badiou, in *conventional* set theory you would say that $\alpha \in X$ but $\{\alpha\} \in P(X)$, equivalently $\{\alpha\} \subset X$.

Comment: Yes :( I think that's where it could get a bit wishy washy notation wise hence my confusion. In most cases Badiou would call $\alpha$ a multiplicity (consistent or inconsistent multiplicity), that can also counted-as-one (forming-into-one)? And when he says it's included somewhere, he most likely means {.} of it is included.

I'm trying to find a way to unify the consistency in the diagram and the maths and his words.